# SQL rollup colum values into 1 concatonated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

What kind of SQL is needed to group by GroupID and then concatonate all of the Name values into 1 row with comma's separating the values?

So this:

```
GroupName   GroupID Name
All screens 139091  Business
All screens 139091  Business 
All screens 139091  Cafeteria/Bathrooms
All screens 139091  Lobby
```

Would become this:

```
GroupName   GroupID Name
All screens 139091  Business, Cafeteria/Bathrooms, Lobby
```

This would need to be done on as many GroupID's as there are in the table and I am guessing skip duplicates. Is this better done on the C# side? The SQL version is 2008 R2

Group_Concat does not exist for use in SQL Server

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation".

Comment: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) The most common one is XML + STUFF (to avoid duplicates use `DISTINCT` in subquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you out.

```
   SELECT GroupName, GROUPID , STUFF(( SELECT ',' + NAME FROM #TAB FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
   FROM #TAB GROUP BY GROUPNAME, GROUPID
```

Comment: You need to add a `WHERE` clause to your nested query... this is not going to work as expected otherwise when you have different group IDs/names.

Comment: @Lucero What would the WHERE criteria need to be?

Comment: @JoJo Probably GroupID would the column you want to JOIN on: `SELECT T1.GroupName, T1.GroupID, STUFF((SELECT ','+T2.NAME FROM #TAB T2 WHERE T1.GroupID=T2.GroupID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') FROM #TAB T1 GROUP BY T1.GroupName, T1.GroupID`